The torchaudio backend is empty
I am trying to read m4a audio file using torchaudio.load() but i go this following error
torchaudio.load("1.m4a")

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 1
----> 1 torchaudio.load("1.m4a")

File c:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\AI-projects\Voice-Gender-Classification\voiceenv\Lib\site-packages\torchaudio\_backend\utils.py:204, in get_load_func.<locals>.load(uri, frame_offset, num_frames, normalize, channels_first, format, buffer_size, backend)
    118 def load(
    119     uri: Union[BinaryIO, str, os.PathLike],
    120     frame_offset: int = 0,
   (...)
    126     backend: Optional[str] = None,
    127 ) -> Tuple[torch.Tensor, int]:
    128     """Load audio data from source.
    129 
    130     By default (``normalize=True``, ``channels_first=True``), this function returns Tensor with
   (...)
    202             `[channel, time]` else `[time, channel]`.
    203     """
--> 204     backend = dispatcher(uri, format, backend)
    205     return backend.load(uri, frame_offset, num_frames, normalize, channels_first, format, buffer_size)

File c:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\AI-projects\Voice-Gender-Classification\voiceenv\Lib\site-packages\torchaudio\_backend\utils.py:116, in get_load_func.<locals>.dispatcher(uri, format, backend_name)
    114     if backend.can_decode(uri, format):
    115         return backend
--> 116 raise RuntimeError(f"Couldn't find appropriate backend to handle uri {uri} and format {format}.")

RuntimeError: Couldn't find appropriate backend to handle uri 1.m4a and format None.


so I checked the torchaudio backend and i got an empty list
import torchaudio
print(torchaudio.list_audio_backends())

[]

I tried installing ffmpeg and librosa and PySoundFile... but nothing worked for me...
I just want it to read the audiofile properly so that i can conitnue with my project

There's a step in https://pytorch.org/audio/stable/installation.html, that if you're installing it from pre-built binaries you still have to install the FFMPEG libs.  It's an important step disguised as a note, below is a that note quoted... revisit the installation page as that has links to the FFMPEG libs that you need to install:

NOTE
This software was compiled against an unmodified copies of FFmpeg, with the specific rpath removed so as to enable the use of system
libraries. The LGPL source can be downloaded from the following
locations: n4.1.8 (license), n5.0.3 (license) and n6.0 (license).


oh ok I will check that and see, thank you!

@SanjithKumar was the hidden installation step the thing you were missing and thus solve the issue?

No actually it didn't work, I simply switched to librosa... for the loading proess...
